# How much vertical space can I recover from a browser?

Tags: browser, usability

I'm trying to maximize my usable screen area when browsing web pages.

Say I'm researching something and I want to open and view as many pages as possible, and as much content as possible.

I can tile windows horizontally as much as I'd like, but vertical space is a bit trickier.

Take, for example, Chrome:
[image: Chrome's... chrome]

Now, there's the easy bit of hiding the bookmarks bar. But what about the address bar and the tab bar? Anything that can be done there? Perhaps other browsers can hide tab and address bars even if Chrome can't?

There is also fiddling with the web pages themselves.

For example, I tried hiding the scroll bars while preserving the ability to scroll:
`body::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }` (or the equivalent for Firefox)

However, frustratingly, there is still a black bar behind the horizontal scrollbar that is not part of any stylable element that I can find.

How minimal can we get?

The best idea I have so far is to create a custom web page with multiple tiled iframes that I can put in full-screen mode, but I've practically never used iframes and I don't relish the pain I suspect that approach would inflict.

Comment: I-Frames are likely a bad choice. Most sites will protect their users by restricting what sites their pages can be framed in. Also, on hiding the address bar, that generally isn't considered safe, in that it makes you much more susceptible to phishing attacks. That isn't stopping some browser makers from trying to minimize the information displayed, but there is some cost/risk.

Comment: As I said, *pain*. Apart from that the only consideration is what sites can do to prevent me from putting them in an iframe. Also I hate browsers trying to hide information from me for precisely the reasons you described.

Comment: Why not just press F11 and have *all* the space for your webpage?

Comment: @Mokubai F11 is one page. Goal is multiple, like I said already.

Comment: F11 is a browser setting, not restricted to one page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Firefox with the [Tree Style Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) add-on. This lets you arrange tabs in a tree structure --perfect for organizing research and work tickets, which is where I originally heard of Tree Style Tabs-- and, in Firefox, you can go full-screen (`F11`) while keeping the tab bar on the side visible (you can also toggle it via `F1`).

That being said, using Tree Style Tabs *effectively* involves setting an `about:config` option and creating a custom `userChrome.css`. So I'll get into the steps below.

### Zero

You'll need to install Firefox, since Tree Style Tabs only works with Firefox. Then, you'll need to install the [Tree Style Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) add-on.

### First

The `about:config` option that you want to enable is:

`toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`

[image]

It defaults to `false`. Toggle it to `true`.

### Second

Then, you can create a `chrome/userChrome.css` file in your **root** profile directory. Visit `about:profiles` and the top profile listed should be the in-use one. It should show you a path to the root directory:

[image]

Open that directory up. You'll probably need to make the `chrome` directory. Then, inside the `chrome` directory, add a `userChrome.css` file. Mine is below:

```css
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

/* Hide horizontal tab toolbar */
#TabsToolbar {
    visibility:collapse!important;
}

/* Hide "Tree Style Tabs" sidebar header */
#sidebar-box[sidebarcommand="treestyletab_piro_sakura_ne_jp-sidebar-action"] #sidebar-header {
    display:none;
}
```

Once you've toggled that `about:config` entry and created a `userChrome.css` file, close the browser and re-open it. Notice that tabs are now on the left, and you have various options for opening new tabs as either children or siblings of existing tabs.

### Demo

No matter how I try, I can't get a useful GIF under 2 MiB to demo this natively within SuperUser. So... you can see a demo here on imgur:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rePdF.jpg

### For Getting Rid of Even More Vertical Space Without Fullscreen

I noticed that one of your comments wanted to get rid of the nav bar and didn't want to use the full-screen feature. I found [this](https://support.mozilla.org/gu-IN/questions/1360600), which will hide the navbar unless you mouse over the region. It's another `userChrome.css` tweak you can make:

```css
/* Hide nav bar entirely unless moused over */
#nav-bar {
  /* customize this value. */
  --navbar-margin: -44px;

  margin-top: var(--navbar-margin);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important;
}

#navigator-toolbox:focus-within > #nav-bar,
#navigator-toolbox:hover > #nav-bar
{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: var(--navbar-margin);
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Between that, removing the bookmark bar, and hiding Tree Style Tabs with F1, you can get down to pretty minimal space taken up without going full screen:

[image]

Notice how the only vertical space taken up is by the `Menu Bar`. Opting to "hide" it doesn't completely get rid of it though, just shrinks it a bit.

Comment: Ah yes. Makes sense it'd be firefox to the rescue. Though I already use a custom style to - you guessed it - recover more usable space after the last FF redesign. It's called lepton (Firefox-UI-Fix on github). I will probably have to manually edit the stylesheet to merge these changes, but it looks very promising. Thank you.